# Weblogic 12c Data source creation issue

Tags: listener, datasource, weblogic12c, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12c and created local user under pluggable DB. To access it through Sqlplus, I have added DB details in Tnsnames.ora file.

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = WIN-VH1MONR8C2R)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PDBORCL)
    )
  )
```

Now I am able to access it through SQLPLUS - username/password@PDBORCL.

Also I able to connect it from SQL Developer - Servicename as **PDBORCL** - **NO SID**

Next I have installed Weblogic 12c in the same machine.

While creating and testing data source I am facing Listener issue. Error Below.

```
Connection test failed.
 Listener refused the connection with the following error: 
 ORA-12520, TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:486)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:174)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:109)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:356)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:22)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:254)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:251)
com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:751)
com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:479)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
```

Please help to fix it.

Comment: Are you accessing locally via SQL*Plus and SQL Developer? Did you check whether listener is up? If you are on the same machine, i.e. connecting locally then you could simply use localhost, no need of hostname.

Comment: Yes I am accessing locally, however Listener is up.

Comment: I am able to connect from client machines too....

Comment: How have you defined the data source? Maybe you can add the config/jdbc XML file to the question, if one was created?